# How can I make it so that once a value in an array is used, it can't be used again until the array is finished?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

On a website, I want a random picture to show up when someone clicks the button. The URLs to the pictures are contained in the javascript file in an array. It's working fine as of now, however I want to make it so that once a picture shows up, it can't show up again until all the other items in the array show up. Another words, I don't want any pictures to show up twice until all the pictures in the array are finished. What do I add to the code below?

```
var images = 
["sample1.png", 
"sample2.png", 
"sample3.png", 
"sample4.png", 
"sample5.png", 
"sample6.png", 
"sample7.png"];
var rand = images[Math.round(Math.random() * (images.length - 1))];

function test(){
rand = images[Math.round(Math.random() * (images.length - 1))];
document.getElementById("picture").style.background = "url('/images/"+rand+"') no-repeat center center";
}
```

Comment: Shuffle the array, then iterate through it.

Comment: Make another array and when the index of an image is computed, set a boolean in the corresponding array to `true`. You can compare against this array for each index.

Answer (score 0):

You could use it like this,

keep track which possibilities are still left, and reset in case there are no new possibilities.

In this case i used a string array, but the principle is the same :)

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D3XSY/

```
var messages = ['hello', 'there', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'test'];
var available = [].concat(messages);
var interval;

function update(id) {
    if (available.length === 0) {
        available = [].concat(messages);
    }
    var ri = Math.floor(Math.random() * available.length);
    var msg = available[ri], el = document.getElementById(id);
    if (el) {
        el.innerHTML = msg;
    }
    available.splice(ri, 1);
}

interval = setInterval(update.bind(null, 'promo'), 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something [like this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q3fU7/1/)

Basically keep a running list of available images and reset it once you've used them all.

```
var defaultImages = ["sample1.png", "sample2.png", "sample3.png", "sample4.png", "sample5.png", "sample6.png", "sample7.png"],
    availImages = [],
    randomImage = '',
    button = document.getElementById('testButton');

button.onclick = test;

function test()
{
    if(availImages.length == 0)
            availImages = defaultImages.slice(0);

    randomImage = availImages[Math.floor(Math.random() * availImages.length)];

    var index = 0;
    for(indexLength = availImages.length; index < indexLength; index++)
    {
        if(availImages[index] == randomImage)
            break;
    }

    availImages.splice(index, 1)
    console.log(randomImage);
}
```